# Is it possible to create a chunky radial gradient with the blend tool?

Tags: gimp

Okay, I want to create a radial gradient (FG to transparent). Not a big deal.

But the gradient shall be kinda **chunky**, blocky, minecraft-like - sorry I'm not a native english speaker and I'm not sure which one of these would make most sense.

So I don't want to have a perfect smooth radient but one consisting out of 1x1 tiles where each tile is like 10x10px.

I hope it is clear what I am asking for :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: step by step guide, as requested by comments:

**NOTE**: my GIMP version is not in english, so I'm guessing the name of the menus.

If looking for a "blocky" look (big pixels):

- Create a small blank image, 10 times smaller than the intended size.
- Follow the steps to create the non-smooth gradient
- Scale the image up: `Image -> Scale Image`, increase by ten the size (both vertical and horizontal) and use `Interpolate -> None`.

.

If looking for "transparent" gradient:

- Follow the steps to create the non-smooth gradient
- Transform background color to transparent using `Layer -> Transparency -> Color to alpha` and selecting white (default value)

.

Creating a non-smooth gradient (bullseye gradient):

Method A: Posterize

- Create the "smooth" radial gradient **using foreground to *white* background**.
- OPTIONAL - Convert to grayscale `Image -> Mode -> Grayscale` to avoid chromatic aberration (this is second step, since foreground color could be non-saturated)
- `Color -> Posterize`
- OPTIONAL - Convert it back to full color `Image -> Mode -> RGB`
- OPTIONAL - Use `Color -> Colorize` to adjust to your desired color (only use the `tone` slider).

.

Method B: reducing color space

- Create the "smooth" radial gradient **using foreground to *white* background**.
- Convert to indexed color `Image -> Mode -> Indexed`
- Convert it back to full color `Image -> Mode -> RGB`

.

Sample imagen: (background white). Smallest blocks are 10px wide: [image: sample blocky-bullseye radial gradient]

Comment: @Chenmunka It does answer the question. Sometimes it's better to leave a hand-crafted comment. [This thing](http://stackapps.com/q/2116) is useful too.

Comment: First: thanks for your answer. But I think this solution won't give me expected results (maybe I'm doin it wrong, I'll play a bit with the posterize function). [Here](http://imgur.com/vC61hkj) is an **very** basical image that shows what I expect :)